# How to draw a box around a certain part of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, posters, a0poster

I'm using a0poster package to create a poster of dimensions 90x100 cm^2. To place text on the page I use `\textblock` command. Now, there are several blocks I want to frame together. The obvious choice is to use `tikz`. This, however, fail miserably. For example, Consider the following

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node (b) [left=50cm of a] {b};
  \node (c) [right=10cm of a] {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

`a` and `c` doesn't appear on the page when I apply this inside a textblock. When I use it outside a textblock, the nodes positions change in an unpredictable way. If I try to use

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (current page) {a};
  \node (b) [left=50cm of a] {b};
  \node (c) [right=10cm of a] {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The results are pretty much the same with the main feature that the position is not constant. Event using `current page.center` isn't constant, which is buffering to me.

How can I, then, draw a line between two fixed points on the poster?

Comment: Is it just about drawing a line from some foxed point to another fixed point? I didn't follow!

Comment: Yes, drawing from point ``(a)`` on the poster to point ``(b)`` on the poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is so complicated. You have to use proper coordinates and `remember picture,overlay` options:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,line width=5pt] (20,-20) -- (40,-20);  %% one line
\draw[green,line width=5pt] (50,-40) -- (50,-80);  %% another line
\draw[blue,line width=5pt] ($(current page.north west)+(40cm,-50cm)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(80cm,-50cm)$);  %% one more line
\end{tikzpicture}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
\documentclass{a0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node (a) at ($(current page.north west)+(90cm,-50cm)$) {a};
  \node (b) [left=50cm of a] {b};
  \node (c) [right=10cm of a] {c};
  \draw[red,line width=5pt] (a) -- (b);  %% one line
  \draw[green,line width=10pt] (a) -- (c);  %% one line
\end{tikzpicture}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]